# Postgres get a list of all user defined trigger functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to achieve a sql query to make a list of all user defined trigger functions. Like the list from pg_admin below.

[image]

When I call:

```
SELECT proname, prorettype,proowner from pg_proc WHERE  prorettype = 2279;
```

I also get predefined functions

[image]

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select all functions and leave out the ones created by the system, you can add a `JOIN` with the table `pg_user` and select the functions that were not created by `postgres`:

```
SELECT p.oid,proname,prosrc,u.usename
FROM  pg_proc p  
JOIN  pg_user u ON u.usesysid = p.proowner  
WHERE usename <> 'postgres' AND prorettype = 2279;
```

Alternatively, you could also specify a user (or many) to the where clause within a `IN` expression:

```
WHERE usename IN ('user1','user2')
```

**EDIT**: see comments. If the sysadmin created functions using the user `postgres` I would suggest to change the owner to another user.

```
ALTER TABLE public.mytable OWNER TO myuser;
```

If for some reason `ALTER TABLE` is not possible, try selecting by language (sql, plpgsql, etc) or just filter out the functions containing the language `internal`:

```
SELECT p.oid,proname,prosrc,u.usename
FROM  pg_proc p  
JOIN  pg_user u ON u.usesysid = p.proowner  
WHERE prolang = 13436 AND prorettype = 2279;
```

Or maybe ..

```
SELECT p.oid,proname,prosrc,u.usename
FROM  pg_proc p  
JOIN  pg_user u ON u.usesysid = p.proowner  
WHERE prolang <> 12 AND prorettype = 2279; --12=internal
```

See table [`pg_language`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/catalog-pg-language.html) to get the oid of your function's language, e.g. of my instance:

```
SELECT oid, lanname FROM pg_language;

  oid  | lanname  
-------+----------
    12 | internal
    13 | c
    14 | sql
 13436 | plpgsql
```

Comment: That is a good answer. Lets say that some inexperienced sys_admin have made these using the postgres user. Do you have an idea on how to fix the problem then.

Comment: @PeterMølgaardPallesen mm.. that's pretty hard. I would give a shot to adding `prolang = 13436` (see the edit to my answer), so that you can avoid any internal functions

Comment: Alternatively one can filter by p.oid being higher that a given number